# Fast way of slicing columns from tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a huge list of tuples from which I want to extract individual columns. I have tried two methods.
Assuming the name of the list name is **List** and I want to extract the **jth column.**

First one is

```
column=[item[j] for item in List]
```

Second one is

```
newList=zip(*List)
column=newList[j]
```

However both the methods are too slow since the length of the list is about 50000 and length of each tuple is about 100. Is there a faster way to extract the columns from the list?

Comment: What do you want to do with the column?

Comment: I dont think you properly profiled your code ... (I dont think this is the step your code is slowing down in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is something numpy does well

```
A = np.array(Lst) # this step may take a while now ... maybe you should have Lst as a np.array before you get to this point

sliced = A[:,[j]] # this should be really quite fast
```

that said

```
newList=zip(*List)
column=newList[j]
```

takes less than a second for me with a 50kx100 tuple ... so maybe profile your code and make sure the bottleneck is actually where you think it is...

Comment: Actually 
newList=zip(*List)
takes most time. The size of the list is about 100 MB. The rest is quite fast.

Comment: @AnirbanDutta but you should only have to call `zip` once, unless you have many of these big lists, so unless your program has to run in less than a second you're fine.